# Why is the validation accuracy fluctuating in every epoch?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, artificial-intelligence

I am trying to build a cattle identification model from muzzle images. I have a dataset of 4923 images of 268 cows. I have used `ResNet50()` model as below.

Hyper Parameters:

```
Batch size: 16
Learning rate: 0.0002
Epoch: 100
Iteration per Epoch: 150
```

```py
base_model = ResNet50(include_top=False, weights='imagenet')
for layer in base_model.layers:
    layer.trainable = True

x = base_model.output
x = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
x = Dense(512,activation='relu')(x)
predictions = Dense(268, activation='softmax')(x)
model = Model(inputs=base_model.input, outputs=predictions)
```

My problem is that the accuracy is low and fluctuates across each epoch.

[image: Fluctuating validation accuracy]

The [research paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/356461977_Automated_Muzzle_Detection_and_Biometric_Identification_via_Few-Shot_Deep_Transfer_Learning_of_Mixed_Breed_Cattle) presents this accuracy:
[image]

Comment: I am trying to apply the method in Section 2.3.2 and 2.3.3 from this paper https://www.researchgate.net/publication/356461977_Automated_Muzzle_Detection_and_Biometric_Identification_via_Few-Shot_Deep_Transfer_Learning_of_Mixed_Breed_Cattle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The model is overfitting because you are training a very large, untrained model on a relatively small dataset.

Some things you can try to overcome this:

**Setting `layer.trainable` equal to `False`:**

This will use pre-trained weights that have been tuned for thousands of epochs so that you do not have to retrain them from scratch. Training from scratch will take millions of examples and lots of computing resources to achieve.

**Decrease your learning rate**

When training a model where the weights have already been pre-trained very well, it is very likely that they do not need much further improvement. So in order to fine tune your model without it unlearning it's already learnt patterns, decrease the learning rate to something between `1e-5` to `1e-9`

**Only train the top layers**

Because ResNet has lots of layers, this means that it also has many patterns learned. Usually, the patterns and layers near the inputs abstract larger, more general information and it is usually a good idea to leave them as is. Layers towards the top, near the outputs however, tend to have more fine-grained details specific to the models problem case. These are the layers you should tweak in order to see an improvement in training an validation accuracy

```py
for layer in base_model.layers:
    layer.trainable = False
for layer in base_model.layers[-5:]:
    layer.trainable = True
```

Also, make your input images are scaled between the range of `[0, 1]`. This can be achieved by dividing the images by `255.0`

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I did the changes that you suggested but when I freeze CONV layers I get very low accuracy, very weird. The paper suggests high accuracy in the case of transfer learning but I don't get the result. The result is only good when I train the RESNET from scratch. 
Here is the link to the paper, section 2.3.3
https://www.researchgate.net/publication/356461977_Automated_Muzzle_Detection_and_Biometric_Identification_via_Few-Shot_Deep_Transfer_Learning_of_Mixed_Breed_Cattle

Comment: How many images are in your validation set?

Comment: Try training for longer because you have very little data, but make sure the model doesn’t overfit

Comment: The dataset is 4923 images of 268 cows. I have added the accuracy in the research paper above in the question.  The research paper trains for 100 epochs, I have done the same.

Comment: Validation data is 20% and training data is 80% of ~5000 images of 268 cows.

Comment: thanks bro, it worked. I had a problem with the normalization of the dataset.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your model is **overfitting**. That means some samples are just classified randomly - since accuracy is nothing but number of samples classified correctly.

To overcome this, try:

1)add more data points (if not more training images are available, try to use data augmentation. In keras see [ImageDataGenerator](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/image/ImageDataGenerator) or try a pre-trained ResNet)

2)Scale images properly

3)change you learning rate to a smaller value.

4)try dropout, batch normalisation ...